# Android webview sdk23 javascript form.submit() is not working

Tags: javascript, android, forms, webview

Thanks for the help. I've used stackoverflow for years and appreciative of all the work posted here.

Is this issue a security or privacy permission now that I did not have before?

I have working code that uses the Android webview. min SDK is 19 (KitKat 4.4) and Target SDK is 23 Marshmallow 6.0.  Test device is a Samsung Galaxy S6.

Everything using WebView.loadURL("javascript: ...") is working. I even have alerts in there to display that the client side running of the JavaScript is OK.

However, this one line does not work.

```
WebView.loadURL("javascript: document.forms[0].submit();");
```

I have also tried

```
WebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.forms[0].submit();", null);
```

(note: I am using "WebView" generically here. My object variable is correct in the code snipet below.)
In all cases, the form does not submit. 
The HTML is fine. I wrote that myself and it is very simple. And ASPX page loaded from a public web server with WebView.loadURL

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="result_android.aspx" id="form1">

    <div >
    <table width=240px ><tr><td colspan=2>
        <img src="../images/bw_main360.png" width="240" />
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2><b>Welcome to our test site</td></tr>
    <tr><td style="width: 84px">Test 1:</td>
        <td><input name="txt1" type="text" id="txt1" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="width: 84px">Test 2:</td>
        <td><input name="txt2" type="text" id="txt2" /></td></tr>

        <tr><td style="width: 84px"></td><td><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" style="height: 26px" /></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Even attempts to "click" the submit button by getElementsByTag does not work.
Lastly, we have tried hard coding the exact form name to rule out every variable and still no luck.

Very little information in LogCat. We've also put bad code in the WebView.evaluateJavascript calls to test that errors are reported.

The WebView is setup in the onCreateView

```
        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

            WebView mainWebView;        

            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }

    @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_main, container, false);

                    setRetainInstance(true);
                    mainWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webMain);
                    mainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                    mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    mainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

                    MyJavaScriptInterface javaInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface();
                    mainWebView.addJavascriptInterface(javaInterface, "HTMLOUT");

                    mainWebView.loadUrl(homeURL);
                    return rootView;
                }

... more code here...
```